# String exercise in Python which detects certain letters

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in Python which allows me to know if a string contains a letter "y" which appears in the beginning of a word and before a consonant. For example, the sentence "The word yes is correct but the word yntelligent is incorrect" contains the "y" of the word "yncorrect", so the function has to return True. In addition, it has to return true if the "y" is in capital letters and verifies those same conditions.

I have done it in the following way and it appears as if the program works but I was asked to use the method for strings in Python find and I havent't been able to include it. Any hint about how to do it using the method find? Thank you very much.

```
def function(string):
    resultado=False
    consonants1="bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz"
    consonants2="BCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ"
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i]=="y" and string[i-1]==" " and string[i+1] in consonants1:
            resultado=True
            break
        if string[i]=="Y" and string[i-1]==" " and string[i+1] in consonants2:
            resultado=True
            break
    return resultado

print(function("The word yes is correct but the word yntelligent is incorrect"))
```

Comment: Instead of checking against two list of characters, one for lower-case and another for upper-case, you could create a single, longer list for both. Or even better, you can convert the string you want to evaluate with `.upper()` or `lower()`. Or is there any reason because you don't want to detect, let's say `"yNcorrect"`?

Comment: `str.find()` returns an index, and only one, so it could be inconvenient for your task unless you want to give it some elegant but unnecessary complications: in your example it will give the index of the first `y` in `"yes"` but not in `"yntelligent"`. Are you sure the task that was given to you consists only in returning True/False, and not in returning the position of the _incorrect_ `y`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is better to use `re`

```
consonants1="BCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ"
for i in consonants1:   
    if (a:= string.upper().find(f' Y{i}')) != -1:
        print(...)
        break
```

Comment: This won't match if the word is the first word in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about solving it:

1. Look up what the `find` function does. I found [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) online which says that `find` will return the index of the first occurrence of `value` (what's passed into the function. If one doesn't exist, it returns -1.
2. Since we're looking for combinations of `y` and any consonant, I'd just change the arrays of your consonants to be a list of all the combinations that I'm looking for:

```
# Note that each one of the strings has a space in the beginning so that
# it always appears in the start of the word
incorrect_strings = [" yb", " yc", ...]
```

3. But this won't quite work because it doesn't take into account all the permutations of lowercase and uppercase letters. However, there is a handy trick for handling lowercase vs. uppercase (making the entire string lowercase).

```
string = string.lower()
```

4. Now we just have to see if any of the incorrect strings appear in the string:

```
string = string.lower()
incorrect_strings = [" yb", " yc", ...]
for incorrect_string in incorrect_strings:
    if string.find(incorrect_string) >= 0:
        # We can early return here since it contains at least one incorrect string
        return True
return False
```

To be honest, since you're only returning a True/False value, I'm not too sure why you need to use the `find` function. Doing `if incorrect_string in string:` would work better in this case.

*EDIT*

@Barmar mentioned that this wouldn't correctly check for the first word in the string. One way to get around this is to remove the `" "` from all the `incorrect_strings`. And then have the `if` case check for both `incorrrect_string` and `f" {incorrect_string}"`

```
string = string.lower()
incorrect_strings = ["yb", "yc", ...]
for incorrect_string in incorrect_strings:
    if string.find(incorrect_string) >= 0 or string.find(f" {incorrect_string}"):
        # We can early return here since it contains at least one incorrect string
        return True
return False
```

Comment: This won't work if the bad word is the first word, since there's no space before it.

Comment: This doesn't work with OP's function as well, as OP also searches for a space before the string

Comment: good point! just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you want isn't find, but finditer from the package 're' (find will only give you the first instance of y, while finditer will return all instances of y)

```
import re
import string

consonants = string.ascii_lowercase
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
for vowel in vowels:
  consonants.remove(vowel)

def func(string):
  for x in re.finditer('y', string.lower()):
    if string[x.start() + 1] in consonants:
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: This doesn't check that `y` is at the beginning of a word. Use `r'\by'`

Answer (score 0):

The function [find](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) returns the index at which the string first begins or is found. So, it returns the *first* index, else -1. This won't work for your use cases, unless you make it a bit more complicated.

1. **Method One: Check every combination with find**.
   You have to two results, one to check if its the first word, or if its in any other word. Then return True if they hit. Otherwise return false

```
def function(string):
   consonants1="bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz"
   string = string.lower()
   for c in consonants1:
     result1 = string.find(" y" + c)
     result2 = string.find("y" + c)
     if result1 != 1 or result2 == 0:
       return True
   return False
```

2. **Method Two: loop through find results**.
   You can use `.find` but it will be counter-intuitive. You can use .find and loop through each new substring excluding the past "y/Y", and do a check each time you find one. I would also convert the string to `.lower()` (convert to lowercase) so that you don't have to worry about case sensitivity.

```
def function(string):
    consonants1="bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz"
    string = string.lower()
    start_index = 0
    while start_index < len(string):
       temp_string = string[start_index+1:end] ## add the 1 so that you don't include the past y
       found_index = temp_string.find("y")
       if found_index == -1: return False
       og_index = start_index + found_index
       ## check to see if theres a " yConsonants1" combo or its the first word without space
       if (string[og_index - 1] == " " and string[og_index+1] in consonants1) or (string[og_index+1] in consonants1 and og_index == 0):
         return True
       else:
         start_index = og_index
    return False
```